# Watir how to logs steps when a script is executed on the browser and how to generate report out of all scripts

Tags: watir

Watir -how to logs steps when a script is executed on the browser and how to generate report out of all scripts 
1)steps of each scrip in a log file 
2)total no of scripts passed and failed
example total scripts 100
passed 90 failed 10

Comment: For (1), it would depend on exactly what details you want to log. Depending on what you need, you might be able to do something in Watir, but it'd more likely be something in your page objects and/or tests. For (2), doesn't your test runner give you those details?

Comment: 1)I want log all executed line of  script and if script fails i want to logs the error message in logs.

Comment: You use RubyMine?

Comment: Which testing framework are you using? Test-unit, Rspec?

Comment: No.I'm using sublime editor.We are using Test-unit

Comment: Please include the program.

Comment: @user2053405, "I want log all executed line of script" still doesn't explain what you are looking for. For example, it could mean log all Watir's interactions with the browser or it could mean log absolutely every line of code (eg setting variables). Does the log need to be in business terms (eg login with user "abc") vs Watir's terms (eg input "abc" into text field with id login)? An explanation of why you'd want to do this and an example would likely help.

Answer (score 0):

For first question on how to *log* execution steps, this is as close as I got since I'm not sure how to log STDIN just yet. So this *logger* is as good as your *puts* comments are.

```
require 'watir'
begin    
  time_now = Time.now.strftime("%y.%d.%m.%H:%M.%S")
  log_file_name = "log_for_script_#{time_now}.log"
  File.write(log_file_name, "")
  $stderr.reopen log_file_name
  $stdout.reopen log_file_name

  b = Watir::Browser.new   
  puts "Browser is opened #{b.exists?}" 
  b.goto "www.google.com"  
  puts "Navigate to google, title #{b.title}"
  b.text_field(:id => "lst-ib").set "logging stuff hopefully"
  puts "setting search parameters "
  puts "and now error"
  asdasd
rescue => e
  puts "error happened: #{e.backtrace.inspect}, #{e.class}, #{e.message}"  
  File.rename(log_file_name, 'FAILED_' + log_file_name)
ensure
 b.close unless b.nil? 
end
```

I guess you could tap into chromedriver/geckodriver logs if you need more detailed logs for your scripts, so let us know if thats the case.

Your second question can be done in many ways depending on how you run/organize your watir scripts. In case you keep your scripts in files/directories you could make another ruby script that executes each file in a directory, and when done, count the failed logs since they are renamed in case of fail.

```
File.rename(log_file_name, 'FAILED_' + log_file_name)
```

As suggested you can use one of testing frameworks that covers logging for you, but that isn't always the employees call.